# Need design suggestions for a generic training data class

Tags: design-patterns, machine-learning

I want to clean up and to generalize my machine learning "framework". 
I have different learning algorithms such as boosting or an ANN which are working with different learning data representations. For example, my ANN implementation is just using data samples consisting of a single real value (and a value representing its class). On the other hand, my boosting implementation uses Haar- like features which are computed on images. Therefore, my training data could consist of images, integral images or single real values.

My wish to aggregate all possible manifestations of the (training) data in a single class but I have not found a nice solution.

Is there a nice design template for such a task or do you know a "smart" solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with machine learning algorithms, but from what you describe it sounds like you have a few sets of classes that perform the same action ("Learn" or "Analyze"), but they do so in different ways (ANN, Boosting, etc.).

I would suggest looking in to the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern. You could build an abstract class (or interface) with the single action that all the various learning algorithm implement.  Lets call this class BaseLearningAlgorithm.

than for each algorithm create a subclass such as ANNLearningAlogrithm, BoostingLearningAlgorithm, etc.

The last thing you need is a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (or dependency injection, or any other solution) to create the subclass you want according to whatever parameter you decide.

This design would allow you to add new learning algorithms easily without changing any line of code you already wrote ([OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)).